# Excel Worksheet Function Month in VBA

Tags: excel

I have a month name in MMM format e.g. Mar and would like to convert to a number in VBA.

In Excel you can use the formula =Month("Mar"&1) to give 3

But, the following doesn't work in VBA: `Application.WorksheetFunction.Month("Mar" & 1)`

I know this works in VBA, but I'm curious why the shortcut above doesn't work?:
`Month("01/" & "Mar" & "/2020")`

Are there some WorksheetFunctions excluded from VBA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there are a lot of functions that don't have a VBA equivalent. A case in point would be formulatext . The reason is that Excel VBA has a simpler way of getting the same output. In your case there is no month under the set of worksheet functions of VBA. Please refer below. Nothing pops up.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bIxb.png)

Answer (score 1):

This will not work:

```
Sub sjkdffhs()
    MsgBox Month("Mar" & "1")
End Sub
```

but this will:

```
Sub sjkdffhs()
    MsgBox Month("Mar" & " 1")
End Sub
```

The space is required to recognize a Date.

Comment: Add the space to recognize a date. That's brilliant, thank you!

This makes sense, the space can be considered the equivalent of "/" e.g. "Mar/1" or "Mar 1" both work.

Answer (score 0):

what does it mean of using `&1`, I think you should only use something like this `Month("Mar")`